# Laravel get orders assigned to my user (with assignments history)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables/models

1. User (id)
2. Order (id)
3. Assignments (order_id, user_id, created_at)

Admin can assign order to some user, then reassign it and I must store this history.

For example I have

```
Users

----+
id  |
----+
1   |
-----
2   |
----+

Orders

----+
id  |
----+
1   |
----+
2   |
----+

Assignments

------------------------------------
id | user_id | order_id | created_at
------------------------------------
 3 |   2     |    1     | 10.10.2010
------------------------------------
 2 |   1     |    1     | 09.10.2010
------------------------------------
 1 |   1     |    2     | 09.10.2010
```

Now I want to get orders assigned to user with id = 1 and logically I have to get order with id = 2 because order with id = 1 was reassigned to user with id = 2 on 10.10.2010

I am using Laravel 5.4 with Eloquent.

Please help me with SQL query or Eloquent relation (I want to have assignedOrders relation for my user's model)

Comment: Why dont you add deleted_at and if the admin reassign the order set the removed_at field and then in your query if you want even the reassign ones add `withTrashed()` else it will return just the current assigned orders !!

Comment: I have another working solution but I wonder how you can solve this problem without any modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting one modification to your Assignments table.

You should add a `status` field which will serve as the following (pending, active, reassigned, done). In fact you should create a new table to store this, but for a quick example, lets stick to this.

This way, you can keep a history of all the Orders. This will also help if for some reason the admin reassigns the order from userA to  to userB and then reassigns it back to userA.

By doing this, your query to get the current user with the Order 1 would be:

```
Assignments::where('order_id', 1)->where('status', 'active')->first();
```

To get a history for the Order, the following query can be used:

```
Assignments::where('order_id', 1)->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

This would display all the Order with the status.

```
-------------------------------------------------
id | user_id | order_id | status     | created_at
-------------------------------------------------
 3 |   5     |    1     | active     | 10.15.2010
-------------------------------------------------
 2 |   2     |    1     | reassigned | 09.11.2010
-------------------------------------------------
 1 |   1     |    1     | reassigned | 09.10.2010
```

Obviously, everytime the admin changes the status of an order, you would need to update the status field and then create a new row on `Assignments` table

Comment: yes this is the best way, and I already did it this way, but for the sake of interest I want to know how to solve this problem without modification.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your query with:

```
orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->firstOrFail();
```

make sure that you are using correct relationships in your model such as has many or belongs to [Docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).